# What is wrong with resizebox usage

Tags: tables, errors, packages

Does anyone know why this is giving me errors?

```
\begin{center}
\resizebox{10cm}{7cm}{
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |}
    \hline
    $n$ & $b(n)$ & $l(n)$ & $p(n)$ \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
```

I've gotten both and error of `missing } inserted` and `too many }'s.`

Comment: Have you load the package `graphicx`?

Comment: I'm not seeing how you can get `Missing } inserted`. Please, be more precise.

Comment: -1: The answer here is "absolutely nothing". So the problem must lie elsewhere.

Comment: Do you try to build a pdf from this? Maybe outdated/beta packages you are using?

Answer (score 2):

You need to load the package `graphicx` in the preamble (between `\documentclass{...}` and `\begin{document}`) with `\usepackage{...}` command, the following code works with no errors, even if the values of `\resizebox` are exaggerated:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\resizebox{10cm}{7cm}{
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} | p{1cm} |}
    \hline
    $n$ & $b(n)$ & $l(n)$ & $p(n)$ \\ \hline

\end{tabular}
}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I did that - that's not the problem.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae then the problem is in code you have not shown, please fix your example to be as here, as complete document, but one which shows the error.